# Artifacts similar to "@YAXPAX@" within memory and IDA sessions

Tags: disassembly, ida

When reversing binaries and parsing memory, I often run across strings like `"@YAXPAX@"` used to reference procedures.  Is there a name for this type of convention?

I believe theses strings are symbol references.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe this strange stuff comes up due to [Name Mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) it is also known as *name decoration*. *Name Mangling* is mechanism used by compilers to pass semantically relevant information from compilers to linkers.

This is how Wikipedia describes [Name Mangling for Visual C++ series of compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++_name_mangling):

> Visual C++ name mangling is a mangling (decoration) scheme used in Microsoft Visual C++ series of compilers. It provides a way of encoding name and additional information about a function, structure, class or another datatype in order to pass more semantic information from the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler to its linker. Visual Studio and the Windows SDK (which includes the command line compilers) come with the program undname which may be invoked to obtain the C-style function prototype encoded in a mangled name. The information below has been mostly reverse-engineered. There is no official documentation for the actual algorithm used.

Comment: Thank you.  This helps a lot.  I would vote up, but I lack the reputation.

Answer (score 8):

(Slightly off-topic)

c++filt is a very useful utility for de-mangling on Unix. I am not sure it is available in Visual Studio as well, but [this](http://ishiboo.com/~danny/Projects/vc++filt/) is a simple implementation you can compile. Compare output (g++, not VC):

```
 $ nm a.out
 0000000100001040 S _NXArgc
 0000000100001048 S _NXArgv
 0000000100000d40 T __ZN6complxC1Edd
 0000000100000d10 T __ZN6complxC2Edd
 0000000100000d70 T __ZNK6complxplERKS_
 0000000100001058 S ___progname
 0000000100000000 T __mh_execute_header
 0000000100001050 S _environ
                  U _exit
 0000000100000e20 T _main
 0000000100001000 s _pvars
                  U dyld_stub_binder
 0000000100000cd0 T start
```

With c++filt:

```
 $ nm a.out |c++filt
 0000000100001040 S _NXArgc
 0000000100001048 S _NXArgv
 0000000100000d40 T complx::complx(double, double)
 0000000100000d10 T complx::complx(double, double)
 0000000100000d70 T complx::operator+(complx const&) const
 0000000100001058 S ___progname
 0000000100000000 T __mh_execute_header
 0000000100001050 S _environ
                  U _exit
 0000000100000e20 T _main
 0000000100001000 short _pvars
                  U dyld_stub_binder
 0000000100000cd0 T start
```

Answer (score 6):

Just a small tip in case you didn't know: You can demangle the names inside IDA via **Options** -> **Demangled names..**.

I believe default is demangle the name in the comments, but you can also change that to the function name itself. Takes away some clutter!

Answer (score 4):

for vc++ name demangling you can use

[vc++filt](http://ishiboo.com/~danny/Projects/vc++filt/)

it is a small wrapper over dbghelp Function UnDecorateSymbolname() that takes the mangled string and prints out demangled names back to the console see below for a snippet

```
??3@YAXPAX@Z
void __cdecl operator delete(void *)
?AFXSetTopLevelFrame@@YAXPAVCFrameWnd@@@Z
void __cdecl AFXSetTopLevelFrame(class CFrameWnd *)
```

snippet

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char buff[0x100];
    UnDecorateSymbolName("??3@YAXPAX@Z",buff,0xf0,UNDNAME_COMPLETE);
    printf("%s\n",buff);
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
void __cdecl operator delete(void *)
```

Comment: "undname.exe" is included with Visual Studio, no need for any extra tools.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [ruby gem](http://zed.0xff.me/2013/05/06/demangle-msvc-delphi-and-c-builder-mangled-function-names-with-pure-ruby) that unmangles C++ names. Its doesn't support GCC yet though what you have there is MSVC.

You could drop this in a ruby shoes app have a name unmangler gui pretty quickly.

Usage:

```
require 'unmangler'

puts Unmangler.unmangle "??3@YAXPAX@Z"
puts Unmangler.unmangle "?AFXSetTopLevelFrame@@YAXPAVCFrameWnd@@@Z"

# output:
# void __cdecl operator delete(void *)
# void __cdecl AFXSetTopLevelFrame(class CFrameWnd *)
```